# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos({2nt})}{n2^n} =$? for any $t\in\Bbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^{2n}}{n2^n} = -\log\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2}\right)$ ,

could you calculate the sum in the title for every real $t$ ?

Comment: Hint: Let $z = e^{i\theta}$ and take the real part of the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\cos(2nt) = \frac{e^{2nit} + e^{-2nit}}{2}$$ we have

\begin{align}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2nt)}{n2^n} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(e^{it})^{2n}}{n2^n} + \frac{(e^{-it})^{2n}}{n2^n}\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(1 - \frac{e^{2it}}{2}\right) + \log\left(1 - \frac{e^{-2it}}{2}\right)\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\log\left|1 - \frac{e^{2it}}{2}\right|^2\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{5}{4} - \cos(2t)\right).\\
\end{align}